# How do loop through a table to select a specific table cell on each row using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html-table, tablerow

I am trying to place text in the 6th table cell of each row of my table. But all I am getting is the first row selected:

```
$('tbody tr:even td:eq(5)').each(function(){
                $(this).text('$145');
            });
```

What adjustment do I need to make?

Comment: Where's your HTML? Also in your post you say "each row", but in the code you are using tr:even?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the following should work:

```
$('tbody tr').each(
function(){
    $(this).find('td:eq(5)').text('$145');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j38SA/).

Reference:

- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: This also works `$('tbody tr').find('td:eq(5)').text('$145');`

Answer (score 3):

```
$( 'table tr' ).each( function() {

  $(this).find( 'td' ).eq(5).text('$145');

});
```

**UPDATE**

Since the accepted anwser does the same thing but using the `:eq()` selector instead of the `.eq()` method, it's worth reading the additional notes on the jQuery DOCs for the [eq selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

> Because :eq() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :eq() cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   $("your-pure-css-selector").eq(index) instead.

So I think it's advisable to use the `.eq()` method instead of the `:eq()` selector.

Comment: I believe the docs warn against `$('#tiny-div p:eq(3)')` rather than `$('#tiny-div').find('p:eq(3)')`. It's finding the `#tiny-div` by traversing the DOM that takes time, not searching inside it.